# getMessages() throwing error

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I tried the following in the console:

```
web3.shh.post({topics: ["a"], payload: "0x847a786376", ttl: "0x1E", workToProve: "0x9" })

var f = web3.shh.filter({topics: ["a"]})

f.get()
```

> [{
>   
> expiry: 0,
>   
> from: "0x0",
>   
> hash: "0x31fd2b2a2103ba67951aed1d00b726bd666a60f5387f171be99b3518c10bece2",
>   
> payload: "0x847a786376",
>   
> sent: 1480886520,
>   
> to: "0x0",
>   
> topics: [],
>   
> ttl: 30,
>   
> workProved: 0
>   
> }]

```
web3.shh.getMessages("a")
```

> TypeError: Cannot access member 'map' of undefined
>   
> at web3.js:3839:19
>   
> at web3.js:4939:28
>   
> at map ()
>   
> at web3.js:4938:12
>   
> at web3.js:4964:18
>   
> at web3.js:4989:23
>   
> at :1:1

What is the mistake with the `getMessages` command? why it is throwing such an error?

Comment: While this question is technically on-topic, I believe, I doubt you will get a satisfactory answer here, since whisper is so new and not heavily used. You're better off asking at https://gitter.im/ethereum/whisper